# react native absolute positioning not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

My button in the code below is positioned absolutely but it isn't working. It is taking up space in its containing view and it is not allowing the image to be below it.

```
<View style={{
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  alignItems: 'center',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flex: 0.5,
  borderRadius: 8
}}>

  <Image
    style={mapStyles.avatar}
    source={props.image} />

  <Button
    small
    icon
    style={{
      positon: 'absolute',
      right: -5,
      top: -5,
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      zIndex: 50,
      elevation: 10,
      borderRadius: 10,
      backgroundColor: '#FF3B3F',
      shadowColor: '#000000',
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 1
      },
      shadowRadius: 1,
      shadowOpacity: 1.0
    }}
    onPress={() => props.updateImage(null)}>
    <Icon style={locationStyle.deleteLocationButtonIcon}
      name="close-o" size={22} color="#9E9E9E" />
  </Button>

</View>
```

The button is the pink bit:[image]

The button needs to be in the top right corner of the image, It is a cancel button. The image should be to the far right where the button is. I have experienced absolute positioning not working in react native before. Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

image styles:

```
  avatar: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try nesting your button inside of the Image like

```
<Image>
  <Button />
</Image
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Not quite how I wanted it to as would have liked it to be just off the edge of the image but it doesn't allow it to overlap the edge. Do you have any idea why my button is not the same height as its width?